# SSH on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, ssh

I want to run a SSH Service on a Pi 3 model B without a mouse or keyboard. 
I would like any solution for running SSH with mounting Raspbian on my laptop .

How do I do this?

And if it is important to mention I have looked at this [topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/).

Comment: How did you create the `ssh` file? If you used notepad on Windows to do this it may have created `ssh.txt` which won't work. A good test for this is to see if the `ssh` file is still present, as your link says it gets deleted if ssh has been enabled via this route. If its still present you might want to see what its extension really is.

Comment: @tobyd, you can create a file without file extension even on the Windows using notepad, the trick is `notepad ssh.`

Answer (score 0):

In the [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) you mentioned, did you see this?:

> 3. Enable SSH on a headless Raspberry Pi
>
> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named ssh, without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card. When the Pi boots, it looks for the ssh file. If it is found, SSH is enabled, and the file is deleted. The content of the file does not matter: it could contain text, or nothing at all.

When you create your SD card with RaspianOS, simply create an empty file called `ssh` into the root of the boot partition. The first time the Raspberry Pi starts up, it'll configure SSH automatically.

Then you find it's IP address (if you didn't set it up manually on the SD card, you can use [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to scan your network (eg: `nmap 192.168.1.0/24`). Your Pi will be one of the devices that have TCP port 22 open.

Comment: I mentioned in my question ..i study the link completly but not work this solution. And when i connect to pi i have any error for connection refused  by port 22

Comment: @milad.ee honestly your post provide nothing on what is not working, nor how you connect your raspberry Pi3 to the network (via ethernet or wifi)? stevieb is trying to provide some directions, if it is not working or if there is any error, what not working and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what can't you accomplish to do:

1) Download and install raspbian on MincroSD

2) After installation and first boot, activate SSH service via `raspi-config` or any other method you prefer.

3) Detouch any mouse/ keyboard and connect via Putty(windows)/ Terminal(Linux or Mac OS) from now on.